# Cannot use Persistent Mode through USB

Tags: system

I recent broke my Hard-drive, so the only way I can use my PC is through the USB, but when I tried going into the persistent mode, all I get is a white screen.

It works on Live mode but not Persistent mode.

Help, I don't know what to do.

Comment: It is a LiveUSB option, where it can save changes, while Live mode deletes changes after shut down.

Comment: I used 4GB when I allocated it

Comment: My USB has 8GB, where 4GB is used for LiveUSB

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? What method did you use to make the drive? Did you check the md5sum of the download? Try the drive on a second computer?